# Algorithm for Calculating Spheric Convex Hulls of Finite Pointsets

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Let the  Spheric Convex Hull ($\mathrm{CH}_S$) denote the intersection of all closed spheres that contain a compact $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and on their boundary at least $n+1$ distinct points of $\Sigma$

> **Question:**
>
> how can the cell structure of $\mathrm{CH}_S(\Sigma)$ be efficiently determined from the cell structure of $\mathrm{CH}(\Sigma)$ in case $\quad n+1\ \le\ \partial\mathrm{CH}(\Sigma)\cap\Sigma\ \lt\ \infty,\quad \Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^n\ $, when $\mathrm{CH}$ denotes the standard convex hull and $\partial\mathrm{CH}$ the set of its boundary points?

An example that shows that the cell structures actually can be different:
take the corners of triangle plus three further points, one to each side of the triangle and slightly outside the circum circle. The cell structure of $\partial\mathrm{CH}$ contains 6 line segments, whereas $\mathrm{CH}_S$ contains only three circular arcs.

[image: Illustration of the difference of the cell structures]

The bigger red dots mark the delimiters of the circular arcs of $\mathrm{CH}_S$

**Edit**
just realized, the spheres that contribute $\mathrm{CH}_S$ can be characterized as follows: after a [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of $\Sigma$ onto the unit sphere of appropriate dimension the contributing hyperspheres correspond to hyperplanes through $n+1$ stereo-projected points that separate the origin from the projected points that are not on that hyperplane; maybe that observation simplifies matters.

Comment: Are not the cell structures identical? For spheres with very large radii through the corners of a triangle face of the hull will approach halfplanes tangent to that triangle. For finite pointsets, the limit as the radii go to $\infty$ is the regular convex hull.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke yes you are right; I will edit my question and add an important restriction, that makes the cell structures possibly different

Comment: Note that the spherical hull of $n+1$ general-position points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in fact a sphere.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke yes, that is the degenerate case; thanks for mentioning it. I wrote "at least n+1" to not rule out that case.